# How to change the color of input text on scroll down event

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

On my website I have search box on top of every page with white colour, I would like to change the colour of the search box same as the background colour of the body page. And every page has its own background colour.

Search Icon/Image is next to Menu (input text is hidden), on click of the same it shows the input text covering all the menus.

We are using wordpress, using Hi-response theme.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We tried to transparent the search box , but the menu was visible.

Comment: We also tried to code using page id but what we have too many pages in future. So we drop that idea but anyways it did not give positive response.

Comment: If you're using `jQuery` look for `scroll()` to detect when the user scrolls up/down and then `scrollTop()` to check the scrollbar position and do your changes if scrollbar it isn't at top 0

Answer (score 1):

```
// Not Tested
    <script>
    $(window).scroll(function(){
            if(document.getElementById("searchBar");.scrollTop() > 10){
    document.getElementById("searchBar").style.color = "Red"
    }
    else {
    document.getElementById("searchBar").style.color = "Blue"
    }
        });
    </script>
```

Edit:

With the background and the search bar the same id.

```
<style>
    #pageTheme {
    background-color:red;
    }
</style>
    <body class="bodyTheme" id="pageTheme">
    <div class="searchBarTheme" id="pageTheme">SearchBar Stuff</div>
    </body>
ID overrides class, so the background color of pageTheme will be projected inherited by both.
```

Comment: Thanks Austin. How do I dynamically code which will fit in wordpress as my team does not have such experty.

Comment: @Dhiren The window scroll function will run when the user scrolls, the of statement gets an element and takes it's distance from the top of the page. When the distance gets within the > 10 it will run the code, if it's above it will run the else code. Putting this at the top of your website will make your page slower but ensure the js is run even if the user scrolls before a whole page load, putting it at the bottom will make the page faster but if they scroll before it loads there could be problems.

Comment: @Dhiren Click the tick if this answered your first question.